# 生气 -> 生我的气 . 的 in a certain grammatical structure

Tags: grammar, usage

I came across the following sentence: 如果不是这样的话，那你为什么生我的气

I haven't seen 生气 as a verb before and was confused by the grammar of 生我的气 but didn't know how to google it as I don't even have the language to describe the situation well. Can someone point me in the right direction to this aspect of Chinese grammar? Thanks!

Comment: ＂现代汉语离合词用法词典＂生气： **［离］** （１）＂生＂后带助词＂着＂、＂了＂、＂过＂、＂的＂等：别去碰他，他正生着气呢。／她一个人在那儿生了半天气。／我什么时候生过气？／你怎么惹他生的气？（２）＂生＂后带补语：你在这儿生了半天气，可一点儿用也没有，反倒把身体气坏了。（３）＂气＂提到＂生＂前：你气生完了吗？就洗洗脸，吃饭吧。（４）＂气＂前带定语：你在生谁的气呀？ **［合］**  （１）合任主语：生气对身体不好。（２）合任谓语：你瞧，他又生气了。（３）合任宾语：你就受生气。（４）合任定语：瞧她那生气的样子！（５）合带定语：他那样的生气谁也不怕。（６）合带状语：你跟他说话的时候要注意，他这个人很容易生气。 **［误］** 他生气你了，你还不知道。**［正］** 他生你的气了，你还不知道。 **［误］** 他一个人生气了半天。 **［正］** 他一个人生了半天气。More examples for ＂明词＂前带定语：生病：他生了什么病？生火；露营的同学们在草原上生了一堆火。生事：这孩子从小到大可生了不少事。帮忙；他谁的忙也不帮，就只帮你的忙。立功：这位连长在对敌作战中立过两次一等功。开口；他都把话说绝了，我还能开什么口呢？讲话：刚才大家讲得全面了，我也就不再讲什么话了。超车：你开得太快了，这几分钟你就超了八辆车！败兴：她败了丈夫的兴，自己还不知道。挨批；他挨了大家的批，

Comment: 可心里并不服。调价：这次要调哪些商品的价？投票；我也投了他一票。转车：你在永安里转哪路车？

Comment: @user65: correction：replace "明词" by "名词"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[生气](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/4615/) is a verb for "get angry; take offence"

'的' in  生我的气 is an 'adjectival particle' that turns the noun '我'(I) into  '**对**我**的**'(**toward me**)

'生气' (get angry) --> '生(对)我的(怒)气' = ( 生气 *at me**) = (get angry **at me**)

*'生气' is a two characters verb, but '气' in '生我的气', is treated as a noun '怒气'*

more example:

'发火' (get mad) -->'发**不必要的**火' = (发 **unnecessary** 火) = (get mad **unnecessarily** )

*'发火' is a two characters verb, but '火' in '发不必要的火' is treated as a noun '怒火'*

A more telling example:

> 问话 [ask word] = **questioning**
>
> 问**你的**话 [ask **your** word] = questioning **you**
>
> '话' here is treated as a noun 'words' instead of part of the two characters word 问话 (questioning)

Answer (score 2):

"生气" is a verb, or often used as a verb: ”他生气了。” “怎么又生气了？”

”生我的气“ specifies the target (or cause) of "生气". So if "生气" means "mad" (or "upset", or "angry"), "生我的气" means "mad/upset ***at me***".

Here's another instance of a similar structure: "沾我的便宜“ => take advantage of ***me***."

In both cases, "我的“ appears to mean "my" (possessive) in Chinese, but "我的“ actually translates into "at me" or "of me", making "me" the target/object of the action (vs the owner/cause of the action).